# understanding a proof on ricci soliton

Tags: ricci-flow

Recently I am reading the book *The Ricci Flow: techniques and applications: Part I: geometric aspects* by Bennett Chow *et al.*. Here I have encountered a result ([Proposition 1.13](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~benchow/257A/MSM-135-Chapter1.pdf)) due to Hamilton which states that "Any expanding or steady Ricci soliton $(g,X)$ on a closed manifold $M^n$ is Einstein. Any shrinking Ricci solution on a closed $n$-manifold has positive scalar curvature."
In the proof, the general Ricci soliton equation is given by $$\Delta R + 2|\mathrm{Rc}|^2=\mathcal{L}_X(R)-\epsilon R,$$ which can be written as $$\Delta R + 2|\mathrm{Rc}|^2-\langle\nabla R,X\rangle+\epsilon R=0.$$ The proof says that the last equation can be rewritten as $$\Delta\left(R+\frac {n\epsilon} {2}\right)+2\,\left|\mathrm{Rc}+\frac {\epsilon} {2}g\right|^2-\left\langle\nabla\left(R+\frac {n\epsilon} {2}\right),X\right\rangle-\epsilon\left(R+\frac {n\epsilon} {2}\right)=0.$$ I can not understand the last equation. Please some one help me to understand this.

Comment: Basically I am concerned with the last two terms in the said last equation

Comment: yes...I mean that...and also \pounds reads as lie derivative

Comment: Well my edit was rejected I think, not sure why maybe lie derivative use square brackets and not angled ones.

Answer (score 2):

It is a direct simple computation We use the followings :

$$\Delta C=\nabla C=0$$ for constant $C$

$$|Rc +Cg|^2=|Rc|^2+ 2C(Rc,g)+C^2 |g|^2=|Rc|^2+2CR +nC^2$$